# Evaluate the value of $f_{mn}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let 
$$ f_{m,n}=\sum_{k=0}^{mn-1}(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{k}{m}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{k}{n}\rfloor} $$.
Here the $\lfloor x\rfloor $ means the floor function. Evalute the value of $f_{m,n}$.

I tried use 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{mn-1}(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{k}{m}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{k}{n}\rfloor}=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}+\sum_{k=m}^{2m-1}+\cdots+\sum_{k=(n-1)m}^{nm-1} $$
but I stuck here.

Comment: This question is a question from [IMC](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/) and you can see it's solution [here](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2013/IMC2013-day2-solutions.pdf)

Comment: You can find similar question in putnam-1998-B4